# Regex to select character between \n and \t with numeric in between

Tags: regex

I have string like this below:

> \n0\tfor [ -2.16891956e+00  -1.90344695e-02   1.95943344e+00
> -2.27888727e+00\n  -7.31571138e-01  -3.84614199e-01  -6.07530296e-01  -4.86286044e-01]\n1\tand [-0.76842052  0.06690284  1.53615272 -1.32009947 -0.52904451 -0.43309262\n  0.68908978  0.08366164 -0.63981813 -1.54382074 -0.13914643 -0.12265489]\n2\tin [ -1.22354347e-02  -5.65219522e-01   5.12757838e-01  -2.44256425e+00\n  -9.62616026e-01  -2.13537860e+00  -2.82485336e-01  -2.24265486e-01]\n3\tfrom [-0.4024832

I want to remove the **\n[numeric]\t** using regex. How should the pattern be?

Comment: So numeric is \d+, `\n\d+\t`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: read the text of the [regex] tag you used and add the requested additional tags please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Python by using the `sub` method of the `re` module which is in the Python Standard Library.

The `re.sub` method takes a regular expression and replaces all the matches in the string with some value.  In this case, we are searching for all digits encapsulated in a \n and \t (`\\n[0-9]\\t`) and replacing them with a space to produce a nicely formatted output.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\\n([0-9])\\t')
string = r'\n0\tfor [ -2.16891956e+00 -1.90344695e-02 1.95943344e+00 -2.27888727e+00\n -7.31571138e-01 -3.84614199e-01 -6.07530296e-01 -4.86286044e-01]\n1\tand [-0.76842052 0.06690284 1.53615272 -1.32009947 -0.52904451 -0.43309262\n 0.68908978 0.08366164 -0.63981813 -1.54382074 -0.13914643 -0.12265489]\n2\tin [ -1.22354347e-02 -5.65219522e-01 5.12757838e-01 -2.44256425e+00\n -9.62616026e-01 -2.13537860e+00 -2.82485336e-01 -2.24265486e-01]\n3\tfrom [-0.4024832'
new_string = re.sub(pattern, ' ', string)
clean_string = new_string.strip().replace(r'\n', '')

print(clean_string)
```

In addition to removing the values requested, I did some additional cleaning by using the `strip()` method to remove any leading or trailing spaces and the `replace()` method to remove the remaining `\n` in the output.  Here is the result:

```
for [ -2.16891956e+00 -1.90344695e-02 1.95943344e+00 -2.27888727e+00 -7.31571138e-01 -3.84614199e-01 -6.07530296e-01 -4.86286044e-01] and [-0.76842052 0.06690284 1.53615272 -1.32009947 -0.52904451 -0.43309262 0.68908978 0.08366164 -0.63981813 -1.54382074 -0.13914643 -0.12265489] in [ -1.22354347e-02 -5.65219522e-01 5.12757838e-01 -2.44256425e+00 -9.62616026e-01 -2.13537860e+00 -2.82485336e-01 -2.24265486e-01] from [-0.4024832
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions which exhibit no effort. There is nothing to suggest that the OP is looking for a Python solution anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention that, but though to try to be helpful anyway.

Comment: Happy I was able to help!  In the future, try to be more specific in your questions to prevent them from being Closed.  Stack Overflow has some guidelines you can read through when creating a post!  Cheers.